# Checkboxes, javascript runs 2 times through function if I click on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I want to click on a checkbox and if I click this box it should run a function what gets an ID and saves it into an array or deletes it from the array if it still exists in the array.

That works, but if I click on the text beside the box the function runs twice. It first writes the ID into the array and then deletes it.

I hope you can help me so that I can click on the text and it just runs once

**HTML**

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="XXX" >Active</label>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
function addOrRemoveBoxes(ID){
    if(boxArr.indexOf(ID) != -1){
        removeFromArray(ID)
    }
    else{
        boxArr.push(ID);
    }
}


$(".checkBoxes").unbind().click(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    addOrRemoveBoxes($(this).find('input').val());
});
```

Comment: Probably you need to use event.stopPropagation()

Comment: I reverted the edit I made to the HTML section of your question because I wasn't clear what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you add the code where you assign your click event to the checkbox

Comment: Sorry the HTML section looks awful I know the HTML section is just a part of a table I create with a each loop

Comment: You probably need to pass the `event` variable into the `click()` callback function: `$(".checkBoxes").unbind().click(function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); //...`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your `label` and your `input` are picking the click. Try to bind it only to input. Like this:

```
    $(".checkBoxes input").unbind().click(function() {
     event.stopPropagation();
     addOrRemoveBoxes($(this).find('input').val());
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't works I think i have to leave out the text now.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is structured bad. When your label is clicked it triggers a click event for the input so you have to separate the input form the label like: `<input type="checkbox" name="opt1" id="opt1_1" value="ENG"> <label for="opt1_1">hello</label>`. Also your jQuery makes no sense, why do you use `unbind()`? And we can't see what `removeFromArray()` does (we can guess but I prefer to see all code used or note that you use pseudo code).

**I made this in 5 min:** *(hopes it helps you)*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    window.boxArr = [];

    $(document).on('click','[name=opt1]',function(){
        addOrRemoveBoxes(this.value);
      
        //show contents of boxArr
        if(boxArr.length == 0){
            $('#output').html('nothing :/');
        }
        else{
            $('#output').html(boxArr.join(" -> "));
        }
    });

});

function addOrRemoveBoxes(ID){
    var arrayIndex = boxArr.indexOf(ID);
    if(arrayIndex > -1){
        boxArr.splice(arrayIndex, 1);
    }
    else{
        boxArr.push(ID);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Choose</h1>
<input type="checkbox" name="opt1" id="opt1_1" value="ENG"> <label for="opt1_1">hello</label> <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="opt1" id="opt1_2" value="DUT"> <label for="opt1_2">hallo</label> <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="opt1" id="opt1_3" value="SWE"> <label for="opt1_3">hej</label>

<br><br><h2>Array contains:</h2>
<div id="output">nothing :/</div>
```

Side note: with `[name=opt1]` we select all the elements with `name="opt1"` attribute.